# Export class members as typescript string literal

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm trying to create a custom string literal type like this one:

```
type MyString = "First" | "Second";
```

Input would be the following class:

```
static class MyStringValues
{
    public const string FirstString = "First";
    public const string SecondString = "Second";
}
```

I assume I have to use a custom code generator to achieve this. Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this working? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you are ok with inline, it should be as easy as

```
[TsProperty(Type = "\"First\" | \"Second\"")]
```

Otherwise, you could always generate the type elsewhere (or have it in your client-side) and then just reference it here